# Non-standard Excel file to csv or pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

[image]

I'm stuck with this problem, I have an [Excel file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b3La9sgbvU2Cy64i2yJhCwGO4CVn8YFC/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=116755756893167842098&rtpof=true&sd=true) and I want to convert to csv or pandas dataframe. But I don't even understand how to start with it? Any help will be appreciated.

I think it will be easier to understand from screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas is made to store "standard" datasets, i.e. a "simple table" with headers and value.

You need a more generic tool, like [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Example taken [here](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2021/07/20/reading-spreadsheets-with-openpyxl-and-python/):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
def get_cell_info(path):
    workbook = load_workbook(filename="yourfile")
    sheet = workbook.active
    print(sheet)
    print(f'The title of the Worksheet is: {sheet.title}')
    print(f'The value of A2 is {sheet["A2"].value}')
    print(f'The value of A3 is {sheet["A3"].value}')
    cell = sheet['B3']
    print(f'The variable "cell" is {cell.value}')
```

Comment: Thank you so much , i`ll try get with it.